# mod_rewrite single "directory" retain the rest of the URL vars

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can I have a single URL var get aliased to a directory, then any additional URL variables stay in the string?

Example:
If I have a contact page and want to swap the "regarding" select based on a quick URL variable.

?page=contact => loads the contact page with all defaults

?page=contact&regarding=bug => loads the contact with the regarding select option for a bug report automatically selected

```
#Enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
#contact,contact/ -> page=contact
RewriteRule ^contact?$ ?page=contact [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ ?page=contact [L]
```

This works fine for domain/contact/, but if I add additional URL variables they get dropped, even if they appear in the URL.

I understand I could do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^contact/bug/?$ ?page=contact&regarding=bug [L]
```

but I would rather have it accept any number of flags in case I wanted to do extra stuff there.

I would like to be able to have domain.com/contact/ and domain.com/contact/?regarding=bug

Comment: I think you're right mario, QSA flag seems to be what I'm after. Thank you.

Comment: Give examples of the incoming URLs so people don't have to guess what your are trying to accomplish.

Comment: faa: last edit (last line of question) has examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending the QSA flag is what I was after. Thanks to mario above for pointing that out.

For reference, the code would be:

```
#Enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
#contact,contact/ -> page=contact
RewriteRule ^contact?$ ?page=contact [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ ?page=contact [L,QSA]
```